# When we thread a bead, what are we doing to the thread?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the word for what we are doing to the thread when we "thread a bead"? Are we "beading" the thread? The closest word that I could find was "extrude" but I think that this is more of a manufacturing term than an arts & crafts term.

Comment: Thread a bead, bead a thread. Pit-a-pat, pat-a-pit. Tomato, tomato. Potato, potato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can both bead a thread and vice versa, as the first sense of the verb *bead* given by the OED is:

> 1. trans. To furnish, adorn, or work with beads.

And it gives citations sush as these:

- 1822 Beddoes *Bride’s Trag.* ɪɪɪ. iv, ― Drops enough to bead a thousand such [necklaces.]
- 1856 Miss Yonge *Daisy* Ch. ɪ. xxii. (1879) 228 ― Morning dew, which beaded the webs of the spiders.

Answer (score 5):

You are *threading* the string through the bead. Definition 2a (2) from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thread).

> to pass (as a tape, line, or film) into or through something  (*threaded* a fresh roll of film into the camera).

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, I'm upvoting. As per the dictionary definition that you quote, threaded is a valid word in this context. However, I do hold the opinion that it is possibly an incorrect usage of the word. Hammer a hammer? No, you hammer a nail. Likewise: Thread a thread? No, you thread the bead. I hate when colloquial misusage is quoted in dictionaries, something that M-W does often. I had a thread on that, but it seems to have been deleted. I do seem to remember that thread having been downvoted into oblivion, though!

Answer (score 4):

This is the ***Provisional*** sense of [verbing a noun](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Verbing.pdf).

If the noun "**`X`**" is a member of a large class of physical things, the Zero-derived Provisional transitive verb *to **`X`***  means 'to provide with **`X`**'. Exemplorum gratia:

- *to seed a lawn*
- *to water a horse*
- *to oil machinery*
- *to roof a house*

(There is also an opposite ***Privative*** sense, which means 'to deprive of or remove **`X`**', ee.g.

- *to seed a pepper*
- *to milk a cow*
- *to peel an orange*
- *to skin a cat*
  )

Since in the Provisional sense the direct object is provided with the verb's object noun, then whether one uses *thread the beads* or *bead the thread* depends on whether it is the beads or the thread that is viewed as the main "possessor" noun. Similar remarks apply to the verb *string*, which is probably more common in construction with *bead*.

Comment: Thank you John. That was very informative, but I do wonder (seriously) if we are lawning the seeds, machining the oil, or cowing the milk. Certainly not all instances of verbing a noun are commutative. What have we done to the milk? Milked it?

Comment: It's far from totally productive, and as you can see it doesn't depend on the verbed noun. If _seed a pepper_ means take out seeds, but _seed a lawn_ means put in seeds, I wouldn't worry much about abstract complexities until the basic stuff is ironed out.

Comment: I see. I just worry that "bead a thread", specifically, might not sound correct. But I'll live with it. Thanks!

Comment: The specifics are going to be variable and unpredictable. For instance, _beading a thread_ might be interpreted as putting the beads inside the thread somehow. When you have two ways to say something and one is a common phrase, using the other usually indicates that the speaker means something different. It's not a matter of "correct" as much as it is a matter of what you want to mean.

Comment: You can fish a burn, and burn a fish.